# How use Spring Boot oAuth2 + Azure AD in a stateless micro-service?

Tags: spring, azure, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

When I try the sample code from [Microsoft Azure](https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-spring-boot/tree/master/azure-spring-boot-samples/azure-active-directory-spring-boot-backend-sample) to use oAuth2 and Spring Boot, it uses a stateful session to check authentication/authorization. You can see this in that:

1. It never passes any headers/JWT on any calls
2. It has a cookie "JSESSIONID" that you can use in new postman session (after obtaining it in a different browser) and it will consider you logged in

This will not work as our micro-services will be multiple instances.

How could I convert this to use a JWT (`Authorization: Bearer AQab...`) for subsequent calls instead of the cookie?

**Dependencies:**

```
//All using Spring Boot 2.0.5.RELEASE
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux')
compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-client')
compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-oauth2-jose')

//Using 2.0.7
compile('com.microsoft.azure:azure-active-directory-spring-boot-starter')
```

**Config:**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.userinfo.OidcUserRequest;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.OAuth2UserService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.OidcUser;

@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity( prePostEnabled = true )
public class OAuthConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{
    @Autowired
    private OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> userService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .oauth2Login()
            .userInfoEndpoint()
            .oidcUserService( userService );
    }
}
```

**Controller:**

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2AuthorizedClientService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2AuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

@Controller
public class MainController
{
    private OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService;

    @Autowired
    public MainController(OAuth2AuthorizedClientService clientService)
    {
        this.clientService = clientService;
    }

    @GetMapping( "checkrole" )
    @ResponseBody
    @PreAuthorize( "hasRole('ROLE__Test')" )
    public String group1()
    {
        return "ok";
    }

    @GetMapping( "/" )
    @ResponseBody
    public String getUser(OAuth2AuthenticationToken userToken)
    {
        //Printing out the oAuth token just for testing
        return clientService.loadAuthorizedClient(
            userToken.getAuthorizedClientRegistrationId(),
            userToken.getName()
        ).getAccessToken().getTokenValue();
    }
}
```

**application.yml:**

```
spring:
  security:
    oauth2:
      client:
        registration:
          azure:
            client-id: ${YOUR_CLIENT_ID:}
            client-secret: ${YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET:}

azure:
  activedirectory:
    tenant-id: ${YOUR_TENANT_OR_DIRECTORY_ID:}
    active-directory-groups: Test
```

### Complete Sample Code

https://github.com/Microsoft/azure-spring-boot/tree/master/azure-spring-boot-samples/azure-active-directory-spring-boot-backend-sample

Comment: Hello! did you find any solution for this?

Comment: @RamonParis We ended up having to write it ourselves. Their solution was never going to work

Comment: @Don Rhummy what manual solution you exactly used for this ?  I have a front end that will pass me (Authorization bearer ) token to my rest API. I have to validate that and allow access to my rest API .

Comment: @Forhad It was three years ago and this was a very complex thing to solve. It's not something I could explain in a stack overflow response, and after 3 years I would miss a lot of details.

Comment: @DonRhummy Indeed, I have coded a workaround for myself .I will try to post a detailed answer .

Comment: @Asraful can you please post an answer? or a link to the solution if possible.

Comment: @SanalS Let me try to find it in my repo.